# PHP SOAP extension not working (PHP + IIS + SOAP Extension)

Tags: php, iis, soap

I'm having some issues trying to achieve a SOAP request to a web service by using PHP.
I have a really small project which only send some requests of a SOAP web service, parses them and show the results on a table, but it's not working. I've developed this using XAMPP and this is the very first time I deploy something on a IIS web server so I'm a newbie.
I'm not using any framework, it's just plain PHP.

The first problem I have is that php_soap.dll extension seems to be disabled since I check the configuration with php_info(); and I can't find SOAP extension in the result, but I've enabled it in my php.ini by removing the semicolon from that line and my extension folder is "ext" under my PHP folder. I have some other extensions running and they're just fine.

Doing some var_dump when I try to instatiate the SOAP class, it's not returning anything (not even null).

Some more info:

PHP Version: 7.3.25
IIS Version: 10.0.17763.1 running on Windows Server 2019

**2022-09-05 Edit**
I've found out that php_openssl.dll isn't working on my server. I don't know why. It's enbled in php.ini. However, phpinfo(); shows it as disabled.
[image: OpenSSL Disabled]

On the other hand, when I run "php -m" command on my CMD, it shows that SOAP and OpenSSL are enabled:

[image: PHP -M Command output]

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is enable the php_soap extension in your php.ini file. You can do this by removing the semicolon from the line that says ;extension=php_soap.dll. Once you have done this, restart your web server.

Next, you need to make sure that the extension_dir setting in your php.ini file points to the directory where your PHP extensions are located. For example, if your extensions are in the c:\php\ext directory, then your extension_dir setting should look like this:

extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"

Once you have done this, restart your web server.

If you still cannot get the SOAP extension to work, please post a comment below and I will try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem.
The problem was not in the PHP.ini file, that one was correctly configured.
The problem was that I hadn't installed an extension for PHP and IIS. Once I've installed **PHP Manager For IIS** and configured it by following [this tutorial](https://www.phpkb.com/kb/article/configuring-php-openssl-extension-with-iis-via-php-manager-on-windows-181.html), it worked out correctly.